# How to loop sort data coming from ajax calls after data has already been fetched through ALL pages?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, sorting, for-loop

I'm having trouble for sorting the array through loop. It works partially every 20 element (sorting page by page ).

Is it possible to loop through all the pages in a website?

It can be around 10 Ajax call to get  all data which is (2000 items).

in the below code my query to fetch the data through Ajax and it works fine  :

```
<script language="javascript">
var current_page = 1, count = 100;

$(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    newSearch();
}, 0);
});

function newSearch() {
count = 0;
current_page = 1;
$('#main').html('');
doSearch();
}

function doSearch(){
 $.ajax({
    
 url:'https://live.ksmobile.net/live/boys?'  
 data: {
        page_size: 900,
        page_index: current_page
    },
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(r){

        var max = $('#limit').val();
        if (r.data.video_info.length < max) max =r.data.video_info.length;

        for (index = 0; index < max; index++) {
            var entry = r.data.video_info[index];
            
                            var level = parse Int(entry.level);

            if ((level > $('#min').val()) && (level < $('#max').val())) {
              count++;
              var HTML = '<div class="entry ' + '"><h="' + entry + '">';
              HTML += '<h3>Level: <span>' + entry.level + '</span> <span>' + entry.name + '' + '</span>id:<span>' + entry.heat;
              HTML += '</div>';
              $('#main').append(HTML);
```

The issue in the below sorting function ,it works only for each page while i need to sort all elements by (level) in the main page .

```
function arr(a,b) {
  return parseInt(a.level, 10) - parseInt(b.level, 10);
}
r.data.video_info.sort(arr);

}
if ((current_page < 100) && (count < $('#limit').val() )) {
            current_page++;
            setTimeout(function(){
                doSearch();
            },0);
        }

    }
});
}
```

I want to display all of the website's pages (sorted) as parts of my main page.
Your help is highly appreciated .

Comment: `VAL()` is not a function. `val()` is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Sorting of paged data shouldn't be done in javascript. You need to edit the backend query to sort it from there. Also, it is a very bad idea to fetch the data of all pages just for the sorting since it will defeat the purpose of pagination and will create a massive lag to your API calls especially if you have a lot of data to fetch.

Comment: There are many approaches to solve this issue but it require experience for sorting arrays in ajax in javascript  ,check that link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266141/how-to-loop-through-all-pages but i am not experienced so that i need some help.

Comment: Not sure what Ajax have to do with any sort and why you think it has something to do with the sorting at all. All it does is call an API and do something to the data returned. Also, the link you referenced is talking about web pages, NOT pages of paginated data